# When does MassTransit route new messages?

Tags: message-queue, masstransit

**Update**: the default queue in question is part of the MassTransit implementation I was researching, rending the question moot.

---

As I understand MassTransit, when you publish a message, the message first goes to the publishing application's default queue.

As long as a consumer is registered for that message type, does MassTransit immediately route the message to the appropriate message queue, or does it wait until a worker thread for that consumer is available?

I suppose what I really want to know is this: *is the default queue a bottleneck?*

I'm using MassTransit 2.7.0 with MSMQ.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a proprietary implementation of MassTransit that won't be of general interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what version of MassTransit are you talking about? And second, what transport are you using?

If you are using RabbitMQ, messages are immediately published to the exchange. Any queues that are bound to the destination exchange will immediately receive a copy of the message. If there are no queues bound, the message evaporates into the atmosphere like an exhaled breath.

When a receive endpoint is created, MassTransit will bind the endpoint queue to the exchanges that match the types of messages consumed. For instance, if a consumer for `MessageA` is connected to the receive endpoint, a binding is created between `MyNamespace.MessageA` and the `input_queue` specified for the receive endpoint. An intermediate exchange, with the same name as the queue, is also created and all bindings go through that matching exchange.

> This makes it easy to wire tap a queue, sending a copy of every message delivered to the queue to another queue for auditing, diagnosis, etc.

If you are using MSMQ, well, that's a different story and one that is ending as MassTransit 3 does not support MSMQ (and publishing on MSMQ is just not a great story, although it works well for send/receive).

Comment: Thank you, Chris - I've added clarifications above.

Comment: Did I sufficiently answer your questions? And 2.7.0 is ancient, 2.10 is the most recent.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out the answer for MSMQ. Since MSMQ is "a different story" than RabbitMQ, does that mean the default queue is indeed a bottleneck? Messages are not read from the default queue until a consumer is available?

Comment: I don't know what a default queue is, the .ReceiveFrom() is what a bus instance receives messages from, nothing else.

Comment: My apologies, Chris. The default bus is a detail of the implementation I was researching, not part of MassTransit itself. Thank you for the help!